# Not port circle radius

Tags: circuitikz, draw

How to set specific radius and color for not port circle(circuitikz).
For example this circle color and radius.
BTW this is just example picture I do not need to code it
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the "not ball" of logic port in `circuitikz` if you choose to use the `ieee` style, but the element is just one, so it will be filled uniformly (see manual, around page 127: http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#99 ):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
        \node[not port] at (0,0) {};
        \node[not port, fill=cyan, circuitikz/ieeestd ports/not radius=.3] at(2,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really need different colors you can build your port:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
        \node[buffer port](RUDOLPH) at (0,0) {};
        \node[notcirc, anchor=west, fill=red,
            circuitikz/ieeestd ports/not radius=.3] at (RUDOLPH.bout) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]